# Pandas: сравнить два df

Tags: python, pandas

Есть несколько `df`, как можно из сравнить через `pandas` для получения слудеюущего результата:

df

```
A  B  C  D  F
12 34 55 5t yh
33 rt gg 34 rr
wd fg tg hh jm
```

df1

```
A  B  C  D  F
12 34 55 5t yh
56 55 55 55 55
```

При сравнение получить следующий результат:
df2

```
A  B  C  D  F
56 55 55 55 55
```

сравнись `df1` c `df` и вывести строки из `df1` которые отсутствуют в `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, должно работать универсальное решение:

```
res = df1[(~df1.isin(df))].dropna()
```

res:

```
    A   B   C   D   F
1  56  55  55  55  55
```

можно было бы поработать с методом `merge`, но тогда будут проблемы, если у вас в датафрейме разные типы данных. приведенный же мной метод будет работать и в этом случае.

Причем, как можно заметить, здесь сохраняются исходные индексы.

Comment: Точно, про `isin` то я и забыл

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, можно короче как-то, но я только через вычитание множеств догадаться смог:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = """A  B  C  D  F
12 34 55 5t yh
33 rt gg 34 rr
wd fg tg hh jm""".split('\n')
data = list(map(str.split, data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

data = """A  B  C  D  F
12 34 55 5t yh
56 55 55 55 55""".split('\n')
data = list(map(str.split, data))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

func = lambda x: set(map(tuple, x.values))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(func(df1) - func(df), columns=df.columns)
df2
```

Вывод:

```
     A   B   C   D   F
0   56  55  55  55  55
```